# If then else constraints - Integer Linear programming - Gurobi

Tags: mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, gurobi, mixed-integer-programming

I would like to express **if then else** statement in a set of constraints using Gurobi via Python API where B and A are binary decision variables.

Here is the statement I am stuck on :

**If** (B[r,u,v,x,y]) **then** A[r,u,x] or A[r,v,y]

**Else**  set the value of B[r,u,v,x,y] == 0 when A[r,u,x] =1 and A[r,v,x]

I know how to express the first part of **if then** as :

B[r,u,v,x,y] >= A[r,u,x]

B[r,u,v,x,y] >= A[r,v,u]

But not sure how to formulate into constraints : when B[r,u,v,x,y] to be 0 if A[r,u,x] and A[r,v,y] are set to 1 in the else part.

Thanks

Comment: Written like that it's ambiguous if not nonsense. Try to write it more formally, e.g by using pure propositional calculus (and state if those are binary-variables or integers; the else-line is unclear about that)

Comment: @sascha I edited my post, hopefully now it is more clear. thanks :)

Comment: Still unclear, but maybe it does not matter (if you know what to formulate): just follow propositional logic in your *else* too; and ignore the fact it's an else in your case! Just treat it as new expression: something like (prototype): ```(a_0 & a_1) -> B < DeMorgan-> (not a_0 or not a_1) or B```. If needed you can create some auxiliary-variable for the first subexpression (```not a_0 or not a_1 == new_var```) (where not is for binaries a ```(1-var)``` and an equality are two implications.

Comment: thanks @sascha. I mean when A[r,u,x] =1 and A[r,v,x]=1 as I put the same index x I need to force B[r,u,v,x,y] to be 0, so do you suggest to follow the propositional logic ?

Comment: Yes. Given it's an implication it's just ```(1-A0) + (1-A1) + (1-B) >= 1```

Comment: Will try it out and let you know if it worked! Thanks @sascha.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157075/discussion-between-user2567806-and-sascha).